# JSON Schema of response in WADL

Tags: json, jsonschema, wadl

Suppose, we have a RESTful API that is described via a WADL file. Request bodies and response bodies (if any) have content type `application/json`. I wonder if there is some standard way of specifying the schema for the request and the response. It would be natural to describe the JSON body with a JSON Schema. I tried to find some informations and these are my conclusions:

- WADL files do not contain schema for JSON body often. They just contain this trivial element: `<representation mediaType="application/json"/>`.
- There is no standard way of icluding a JSON Schema to a WADL file according to the WADL specification (https://www.w3.org/Submission/wadl/).
- WADL files can contain a XML Schema. This would be fine for XML responses. I can describe the structure of JSON via XML Schema if I suppose some mapping between XML and JSON. There is no single standard mapping for this purpose however.

I conclude that there is no standard way of describing the schema for a JSON request / response in a WADL file. There is even no usual (de facto standard) workaround to accomplish this task.

Is my conclusion correct?

Thanks.

**EDIT**:

I would say that JSON is the most common format for a RESTful API and that schemas for requests and responses are essential to describe the API. Hence, everyone who describes a RESTful API with a WADL file needs either to inline or to reference a JSON Schema somehow. And there should be a single standard way of doing this as it is a pretty standard requirement. Moreover, this "standard way" should be understood by tools working with WADL files (like SoapUI) so that these tools can e.g. generate a sample request including the JSON body.

However, it seems to me that there is no such standard way. I am just trying to ask whether I have overlooked something.

I know that I can describe JSON request/response body via a Swagger descriptor in a way that is close to JSON Schema. However, I am forced to use WADL in my project.

Comment: Did you get any resolution to thsi, i mean json schema in wadl.

Comment: @rootExplorr Unluckily, I didn't.